# Любые англоязычные ресурсы содержат огромное количество новой для меня информации

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

Нужно ли обособлять запятыми "новой для меня"? Просьба объяснить.

Answer (score 1):

Любые англоязычные ресурсы содержат огромное количество ***новой для меня*** информации.

Здесь нет обособления,  определительный оборот ***новой для меня*** находится перед определяемым словом **информации.**

Сравнить: Любые англоязычные ресурсы содержат огромное количество  информации, ***новой для меня.*** Здесь оборот обособляется в позиции после определяемого слова.